# Выбор нужного сеттера

Tags: java, lombok

Задача заключается в следующем:
есть некий класс  `SearchParam` который обернут декораторами `@Getter` и `@Setter`. Допустим, что у нас есть экземпляр данного класса `filter` и некий объект `inputName`, который содержит в себе две переменные (`String ident = "name"`, `String value = "Jhon"`); как, зная то, что `ident` имеет строковое значение `name`, которое абсолютно всегда совпадает с названием одной из переменных объекта класса `SearchParam`, вызвать нужный сеттер (тут стоит учитывать, что `SearchParam` может содержать различные переменные, нас должно беспокоить только то, что название переменной будет "100%" совпадать с `ident`)?

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;


@Getter
@Setter
public class SearchParam {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String comment;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения своей задачи воспользовался [отражениями в Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html), классом [Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html).

```
private void bindDataToFilter () {
        Method method;

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : filterTextFields.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey(); //Название переменной экземпляра
            String value = entry.getValue(); //Значение, которое должно попасть в key

            String methodName = "set" + StringUtils.capitalize(key);

            try {
                method = filter.getClass().getMethod(methodName, String.class);
                method.invoke(filter, value);
            } catch (SecurityException | NoSuchMethodException ignored) { } catch (IllegalAccessException |
                    InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Предположим, что класс, которым является объект `inputName`, выглядит следующим образом:

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
static class Input {
    private String ident;
    private Object value;
}
```

Тогда можно создать map, в которой:

- Ключ - это имя поля, которое необходимо засетить
- Значение - логика, по которой будет сетиться поле

Например:

```
Map<String, BiConsumer<Object, SearchParam>> searchParamSetters = new HashMap<>();
searchParamSetters.put("id", (input, searchParam) -> searchParam.setId((Long) input));
searchParamSetters.put("name", (input, searchParam) -> searchParam.setName((String) input));
searchParamSetters.put("comment", (input, searchParam) -> searchParam.setComment((String) input));

SearchParam searchParam = new SearchParam();
Input nameInput = new Input("name", "Johnny");

searchParamSetters.get(nameInput.getIdent()).accept(nameInput.getValue(), searchParam);
```

Минус данного подхода в том, что для каждого нового поля в классе `SearchParam` необходимо будет иметь соответствующее значение в мапе.
Так же следует подумать о том, что делать случае, когда в мапе нет значения для `Input.ident`

Comment: Так же, альтернативным решением могло бы быть использование Reflection API